# Giving Error on My Project

Tags: android

i'm new to android. I've import the project from my `My Computer - Driver` After that it seems to be error with an exclamatory symbol on my project name's left side in my Eclipse. What'll i do for that. I've searched for that. They tells to clean the project.

I've clean my project lot of time. And, also restarted my eclipse. But, the symbol won't go and didn't run my application on Eclipse.

Comment: What is the error message? Check the problems tab.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've got by SpK's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is why you've that means, Sometimes some `.jar` or some other file may be missed. So, just check that with following steps -

Select your project > Properties > Java Build Path

It'll show what files are missed. And, you can import there with missed file with `Add jars` or `Add external jars`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes you're right. It seems to missed my `twitter` jar file. Thanks for your response.

Comment: It also happens if the minSdkVersion or some other optional manifest piece is missing, but is required for uploading to the market. Also, when importing older Eclipse projects, this kind of error is given before default.properties is converted to project.properties.

Comment: Refer here - [Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) If my answer was helpful to you means, then accept that